# Bazel does not evaluate empty defined variables

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have defined a rule in a bazel file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_push")

def branch_aware_container_push(**kwargs):
    tag = kwargs.pop("tag", "latest")
    branch_name = "$(BRANCH_NAME)"
    branch_aware_tag = "{version}-{branch_name}".format(version = tag, branch_name = branch_name) if branch_name != '' else tag

    container_push(
        tag = branch_aware_tag,
        **kwargs
    )
```

And this is how I defined `BRANCH_NAME` in bazel.rc file. I intentionally keep it empty:

`run --define BRANCH_NAME=`

The issue raises in the case that `BRANCH_NAME` is empty, and `branch_name` variable fills with the exact phrase `$(BRANCH_NAME)`, not empty string.

I tried passing context `ctx` to the rule in order to access BRANCH_NAME via:

`branch_name = ctx.attr.BRANCH_NAME`

But seems like the context object is not built and sent by the invoker:

`Error: branch_aware_container_push() missing 1 required positional argument: ctx`

If there is any unclear stuff please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Bazel doesn't support variables in that way. If the branch names are a known set of strings, you can use `config_setting()` and `select()` with `--define`. Something like this:

`BUILD`:

```
load(":defs.bzl", "branch_aware_container_push")

branch_aware_container_push(
  name = "my_target",
)
```

`defs.bzl`:

```
def branch_aware_container_push(**kwargs):
    tag = kwargs.pop("tag", "latest")
    branch_name = select({
        "//config_settings:branch_foo": "-foo",
        "//config_settings:branch_bar": "-bar",
        "//config_settings:branch_baz": "-baz",
        "//conditions:default": "",
    })

    branch_aware_tag = tag + branch_name
    
    # Using a small Starlark rule in place of the real docker rules for simplicity
    my_rule(
        tag = branch_aware_tag,
        **kwargs
    )

def _impl(ctx):
    print("tag is: " + ctx.attr.tag)
    return []

my_rule = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {
        "tag": attr.string(),
    },
)
```

`config_settings/BUILD`:

```
config_setting(
  name = "branch_foo",
  define_values = { "branch_name": "foo" },
)

config_setting(
  name = "branch_bar",
  define_values = { "branch_name": "bar" },
)

config_setting(
  name = "branch_baz",
  define_values = { "branch_name": "baz" },
)
```

One issue is that `selects()`s cannot be resolved within macros (macros are evaluated before configuration information is known, and `branch_aware_container_push` is a macro). So you cannot do `if branch_name` (it will be a select object and will always be "True"). And using `str.format()` with the `select()` object won't work because it will be some string-ified version of the select, not the value you want. But you can add `select()` objects and other things and they will be evaluated later, so you can do things like adding the "-" to the branch name in the `config_setting` value and adding the tag directly.

If the branch names are not known, then `select()` won't work very well because these have to be explicitly listed inside a BUILD file. The other option is Starlark build flags, which will allow arbitrary values, but the rules you're using must have support for the specific flag and operation that you want. So this might be a feature request to [rules_docker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker). It appears though that rules_docker is no longer maintained and deprecated.